# How can i change a button background color in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a button with a condition:
if the color is 'red' it will turn into 'green' and reverse.
I tried to write this code but nothing changes.

```js
function changeColor() {
  var f = document.getElementById(food).value;
  switch (f) {
    case "morning":
      var m = document.getElementsByName(FoodM);
      if (m.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
        m.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else {
        m.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      break;
    case "evning":
      var e = document.getElementByName(FoodE)
      if (e.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
        e.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else {
        e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<td class="auto-style1" style=" width: 88px">
  <input id="food" onclick='changeColor()' name="FoodM" type="button" value="morning" style="width: 88px; height: 75px; background-color:red;font-size:medium" /></td>
<td></td>
<td class="auto-style1" style=" width: 88px">
  <input id="food" onclick='changeColor()' name="FoodE" type="button" value="evning" style="width: 88px; height: 75px; background-color:green;font-size:medium" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
```

what am I doing wrong?

thank you.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`

Comment: Yes, it would be better to use a class named food and give a unique id to your buttons. It would be also easier to use them like 
`document.getElementById("FoodM")` because the getElementById returns a single element instead of an array.

Answer (score 4):

The value of `document.getElementsByName` should be between " " -s. Like

```
var m = document.getElementsByName("FoodM")[0]
```

Besides, `document.getElementsByName` returns an array, so in you have only 1 element with the FoodM name, you should return the 1st element of the array by adding `[0]` at the end.

Comment: I tried what you said but it still doesn't work. There is a problem with the line :var f= document.getElementById(food).value;

Comment: @shira1954 same idea for `"food"`. Should be between quotation marks

Answer (score -1):

The id 'food' appears more than once in the document.
Ids should be unique.